# Testing the numbers of rows created with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I'm making a functional test with laravel / Phpunit

What I expect is having 2 rows with championship_id = 123

But the content of each row may vary.

I only know how to check if a row exists :

```
$this->seeInDatabase('championship_settings',
            ['championship_id' => $championship->id,
            ]);
```

but I don't know how to check that there is 2 rows corresponding to criteria

Any idea how should I do it???

Answer (score 0):

U can use `seeNumRecords($expectedNumber, $table, $criteria)`.

```
<?php
$this->seeNumRecords(2, 'championship_settings', ['championship_id' => $championship->id]);
?>
```

- `param int $expectedNumber` Expected number
- `param string $table` Table name
- `param array $criteria` Search criteria [Optional]

See http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Db#seeNumRecords

Comment: Error: Call to undefined method TreeTest::seeNumRecords()
This is Codeception, and not part of PHPUnit. Is it only available with Codeception??? Right now, I am not using Codeception...